# How to deploy a web application on iphone?

Tags: deployment, web, iphone

I have developed a website in asp.net for iPhone.
Now I am stuck in how to deploy that site on the iphone?
Never done it before.
How to make it iphone ready so the device can access the site ?
Any ideas...

Thank you All.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Social Circus, as Mehrdad says you don't *need* to change anything to allow users with iPhones to access your site; iPhones use a mobile version of Safari that renders pretty much everything like a normal desktop browser.  There are a few things worth noting however if you want iPhone users to have a good experience browsing your site:

- No Flash.  If you've used Flash at all in your site it won't work on iPhones (or most other mobile platforms).
- The resolution of the iPhone is 320x480.  The top and bottom bars will take off a minimum of 20+44 = 66 pixels.  You could implement a CSS template that re-formated everything into 320 pixel width but this is a lot of work.  See something like Google Mail in an iPhone browser for an example.
- iPhone users will be able to add a shortcut to your webapp on their desktop, with a name they want, so the actual URL matters less from this perspective.
- Finally, it's worth noting that many iPhone users think of webapps as a bit "passe" - a bit old (man that's sooo 2008!).  This isn't really fair but it's mostly true.  With 65,000+ apps on the app store no-one's going around looking for webapps any more.  For a better chance of adoption, especially if it's something like a game, perhaps look at using the SDK to write an iPhone-specific version? (quite a lot of work usually!!)

Hope that helps

Comment: I got to this question from a completely unrelated search but really appreciate the respectful and helpful nature of your answer. On a vague question you've provided useful perspective.

Answer (score 4):

Copy the stuff to the Web server, setup the databases if necessary, just as you'd do for a Web app designed for desktop browsers. Is this a real question?

Comment: actually, i want the url to be like www.mywebapp.com

Comment: I can't see how it's different from deploying an ASP.NET Web site for desktop browsers. You'd purchase a domain name you like and point it to the correct IP address and upload your files to the Web server.

Comment: +1. There's nothing special about looking at a website from the iPhone. You don't publish it to the device, just like you don't "install the internet" on computers.